# In Perl, how can I compare dates & times in ISO Format (%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)?

Tags: perl, date

I am looking for comparing two dates (dynamically received from a file ) in ISO Format — e.g. `2011-12-14T17:22:52Z` — in Perl.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

The great advantage of the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation that you show is that it can be compared with string comparisons:

```
my $v1 = "2011-12-14T17:22:52Z";
my $v2 = "2012-01-03T19:13:49Z";

print "$v1 earlier than $v2\n" if $v1 lt $v2;
```

This assumes the values are all in Zulu time (Z is the time zone, aka UTC).  If you have different time zones, then you need to normalize to a single time zone (UTC is a sensible choice) and then compare.

---

Note carefully the term ['*string comparison*'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators).

In Perl, the `<` operator compares two numbers. The values presented will be coerced into a number by hook, crook, or brute force and ignorance. For example, `if ("A" == "B")` is true, because `"A"` treated as a number is 0, and so is `"B"`. The date/time strings will be treated as if the number was the year component only if you use a numeric comparison.

The string comparison operators (whose mnemonics might be based on the original Fortran comparison operators: `lt`, `le`, `gt`, `ge`, `eq`, `ne` and `cmp`) are used for comparing strings. You use the numeric comparators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, `==` and `<=>`) to compare numbers. Be careful to distinguish which type of comparison you want to do.

Comment: Nit: You need to `uc` the string before comparing them because both "t" and "T" are allowed, and both "z" and "Z" are allowed.

Comment: Note: That specific format is called RFC 3339. It is used by Atom (among others), except that Atom only allows uppercase "T" and "Z". Parsers and formatters for DateTime: [DateTime::Format::RFC3339](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::RFC3339), [DateTime::Format::Atom](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Atom)

Comment: ISO 8601 pre-dates RFC 3339 by quite a margin.  It may also be co-opted by RFC 3339 (it's perfectly sensible for the later standard to adopt the format espoused by the earlier), but the format originates with ISO 8601.

Answer (score 2):

If your dates are *not* necessarily in the same time zone (the question did not explicitly mention this), then you'd be better off using a dedicated date & time module than parsing and calculating date strings yourself. Here's an example using the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) and [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aISO8601) modules:

```
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

my $dt1 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime('2011-12-14T17:22:52Z');
my $dt2 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime('2011-12-14T17:22:52+01:00');

if ($dt1 < $dt2) {
    print "$dt1 is first\n";
} else {
    print "$dt2 is first\n";
}
```

Note that comparison uses the *numeric* comparison between two objects, unlike the *string* comparison in the string-based answer. This works because `DateTime` has overloaded the comparison operators and the string interpolation "operator".

Comment: One way of looking at the issue is that the sample date included the `Z` (Zulu time, or UTC) time zone designation, and because that isn't usually used by people unless they're technogeeks (e.g. I use it sometimes), the dates are (probably) all in the same time zone and that time zone is UTC. Nevertheless, if the time zones do vary, the simple string comparison is inadequate. For example, `2015-01-01T04:30:00+12:00` is earlier than `2014-12-31T14:28:00-08:00` — the former corresponds to `2014-12-31T20:30:00Z` and the latter to `2014-12-31T22:28:00Z`. Using a package to handle this is sensible.